# Is it possible to override the setter for an attribute of a class that does not inherit from a superclass?

Tags: python

my class has an attribute which is directly assigned a value, simply by calling Class.attribute = value. However, I would like to run some checks before this value is set, my question is if it is possible to do it without defining a setter method which is explicitly called for this purpose. The class does not inherit from a superclass, meaning that i cannot use the following method:

```
@Superclass.attribute.setter
attribute(self):
###insert custom code here
```

I have tried omitting the superclass, but this gives me the error that "attribute is not defined" even though it is defined in the init method.

Comment: You should not override the superclass attribute. You should make a copy of your own, and then do anything you want with it. Put a `hasattr` check on the super class before setting it, so your code doesn't break when the attribute in the superclass is changed for some reason.

Comment: Provide an exact example of the class. It's not clear if you are referring to a class attribute or an instance attribute.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, You should not override the superclass attribute. Your code will break if the super class is changed.

You should make a copy of your own, and then do anything you want with it. Put a `hasattr` check on the super class before setting it (copy of the attribute), so your code doesn't break when the attribute in the superclass is changed for some reason.